# Postman - Firebase notification ios

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, postman, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to send POST to firebase with Postman but i have an error :

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
        <H1>Unauthorized</H1>
        <H2>Error 401</H2>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here is my body and header.
For authorization I am not sure, I put the api server key of my ios firebase project.
I'd like to send it and show the notification on my device.

Thank you for the help.

[image: HEADER]

[image: BODY]

When I launch the app with xcode, I got fail to fecth APNS but at the end : connected to FCM.

```
<FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
2016-08-25 07:58:06.690 HelloCordova[2426:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
2016-08-25 07:58:06.741 HelloCordova[2426:671139] Firebase Crash Reporting: Successfully enabled
2016-08-25 07:58:06.754: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-08-25 07:58:06.755: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
2016-08-25 07:58:06.764: <FIRMessaging/INFO> FIRMessaging library version 1.1.0
2016-08-25 07:58:06.776: <FIRMessaging/WARNING> FIRMessaging AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification receiver handlers. Add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-08-25 07:58:06.780 HelloCordova[2426:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2016-08-25 07:58:07.361: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> APNS Environment in profile: development
2016-08-25 07:58:07.574 HelloCordova[2426:671139] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2016-08-25 07:58:07.796 HelloCordova[2426:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
2016-08-25 07:58:07.819 HelloCordova[2426:671139] Connected to FCM.
2016-08-25 07:58:08.316 HelloCordova[2426:671139] Finished load of: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/1DE45D4B-AFB3-4F6D-83D7-71D1A6FE8F44/HelloCordova.app/www/index.html#/connected
2016-08-25 07:58:10.094 HelloCordova[2426:671139] THREAD WARNING: ['GoogleMaps'] took '472.765137' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2016-08-25 07:58:33.836 HelloCordova[2426:671139] Received memory warning.
```

Comment: as you can see, it doesn't give me the token of the FCM connection there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `Authorization` tag in `Postman`, you'll need to put format like `key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY`.

To get the `Server Key`: Go to your project settings in firebase console.
Click on Cloud Messaging and copy `Server Key` mentioned in that page.

Comment: Moreover I tested with this link and it is ok https://cordova-plugin-fcm.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use this line any Where in your code to print Device Token

[image]

```
print("Token \(FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!)")
```

Refer the following images for send Push Notification Through Postman

[image]