# Send notification by Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notification to specific user when logged in , I use Firebase messaging and I can send notification by console but I want send this notification in Swift code by using send to topic and `http` request.  I couldn't to implement http request to send notification when I run the code in postman I have this error :

> The request was missing an Authentification Key (FCM Token). Please,
>   refer to section "Authentification" of the FCM documentation, at
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.
>
> Error 401

Comment: the error tells you are missing a FCM token. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787373/firebase-fcm-how-to-get-token

Comment: i want this in ios not android !

Comment: Can you please provide your request code so we can see what might be missing?

Comment: {
  "condition": "'mahdi' in topics",
  "priority" : "high",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
    "title" : "FCM Message"
  }
}

Comment: You need to pass the server key to Postman. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133832/postman-firebase-notification-ios and other answers in this list: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-cloud-messaging%5D+postman

Answer (score 1):

401 Error pertains to an [Authorization Error](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes):

> The sender account used to send a message couldn't be authenticated. Possible causes are:
>
> - Authorization header missing or with invalid syntax in HTTP request.
> - Invalid project number sent as key.
> - Key valid but with FCM service disabled.
> - Request originated from a server not whitelisted in the Server key IPs.
>
> Check that the token you're sending inside the Authentication header is the correct Server key associated with your project. See [Checking the validity of a Server key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#checkAPIkey) for details.

Make sure you're using the correct Server Key from your Firebase Console, under the Cloud Messaging Tab. Steps below.

1. Go to your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and select the corresponding project.
2. Then on left-side panel, click on the **gear button** and select **Project Settings**.
3. Then go to the **Cloud-Messaging Tab**.

The **Server Key** should be visible from there. This the key that you include in the request when sending a message. Make sure that you're properly setting the headers.

You can also do this [using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309674/fcm-with-postman-the-request-was-missing-an-authentication-key-fcm-token/45310143#45310143) or [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664911/firebase-cloud-messaging-send-click-action/44665817#44665817)